# Como usar clase teclado sin tener que usar un constructor

Tags: java, eclipse

tengo una pregunta y es que tengo una clase teclado con varios métodos (readString, readInt, readBoolean,...)

La cosa es que un compañero me ha dicho que para usarla tengo que importarla y crear un constructor (sería: `import static ejercicio3.ConsoleInput.*;`  ) y el constructor tanto de teclado como de la consola:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

ConsoleInput consola = new ConsoleInput(keyboard);
```

Y a la hora de usarlo por ejemplo con la variable `nombre`:

```
nombre = consola.readString();
```

¿No debería de haber alguna forma de usarlo sin usar el constructor y escribiendo el método directamente? Lo he intentado solo importando y escribiendo

`nombre=readString();`

Pero no me funciona

Comment: La cosa es que entonces tal vez te convengan mejor como traits o como interfaces

Comment: ¿Por que no quieres usar el constructor? en el ejemplo que usas la clase `ConsoleInput` necesita un objeto `Scanner` entonces de alguna forma se lo debes pasar, usar el constructor es una buena manera para hacer eso

Answer (score 1):

Para usar un método directamente de la clase sin usar constructor debe ser con un método estático, te coloco un ejemplo:

```java
public class ConsolaInput {
    private static String entrada;

    public static void Input(String s){
        entrada= s;
    }

    public static void Imprimir(){
        System.out.println(entrada);
    }
}
```

Para ejecutarlo:

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsolaInput.Input("Hola Mundo");
        ConsolaInput.Imprimir();
    }

}
```

Si quieres acceder a un atributo de la clase debe ser declarado como estático también.

Te dejo un enlace con mas información sobre la palabra reservada `static` [Directiva Static](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/09/17/la-directiva-static-en-java/)

Espero te sirva

Comment: Solo una observacion los métodos estáticos deben ser escritos con su primera letra en mayúscula esto es por convenciones de escritura de java. https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/3cu10n/do_any_of_you_start_static_methods_with_a_capital/

Comment: Es correcto ya lo modifico en la solución

Comment: De hecho eso no es correcto, la convención oficial de Java no dice que los métodos estáticos deban tener su primer letra en mayúscula, en general los métodos, independientemente de que tipo sean deben empezar en minúscula (esta es la documentación oficial https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html ver la sección de "Methods"), otros lenguajes si lo recomiendan, como C#